# Bash - output to loop using find

Tags: bash, loops, find

I have a list of files in a file (files.txt):

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

When I execute:

```
cat files.txt | while read line; do find -name $line >> outfile.txt; done
```

Why don't I get an outfile with a list of those files' paths?

Whereas if I execute:

```
find -name file1.txt >> outfile.txt
```

the task is performed

Many thanks

Clive

Comment: Did you edit `files.txt` on a Windows box, and then copy it to a unix or linux server without converting line endings from DOS format?  Please check the output of `od -c files.txt | head`, and append it to your question if it's unclear what you're looking at.  Oh, and make sure you quote your variables. Special characters in unquoted variables can cause unpredictable results!

Comment: Hi @ghoti, yes thanks. How do I convert the line endings?

Comment: Answered, below.  Enjoy!  :)

Comment: @user3329732 On a side note. You should really have your script first create an array of files and pass the array to `find`, so it only has to do one. Otherwise, you're traversing the same tree multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you edited `files.txt` on a Windows box, then copied it to your Linux or Unix server without converting line endings.  This is not an uncommon problem, and multiple solutions exist.  :)

Windows uses CR+LF (`\r\n`) for newlines, whereas unix and linux use only LF (`\n`).

The first and possibly easiest option may be to re-copy the files with the appropriate conversion in place, if your copy program supports such a thing.  If you copied the files using FTP protocol, check your client for a "type" option, which may be set to "ascii" or "bin".  Depends on your client.  If you're using something like `scp`, which transfers only binary files, then read on.

Another tried-and-true option is to use the `dos2unix` application which may already be installed on your unix or linux server.  If it's not, you may be able to install it using your machine's package manager.  (I don't know how, because you haven't mentioned what operating system you're using.)  If installed, documentation for using `dos2unix` can be found by running `man dos2unix`.  For example, if you want to convert all the text files matching `*.txt` in the current directory and all subdirectories under the current one, you might use the following:

```
find . -type f -name \*.txt -exec dos2unix -k -o {} \;
```

The options here work are as follows:

- `find .` - tells find to search recursively, starting from the current directory.
- `-type f -name \*.txt` restricts our search by file type and glob.
- `-exec` runs the rest of the line up to `\;` on each file, with `{}` replaced with the filename.
- `dos2unix` - well, you know.
- `-k` - "keep" the timestamp on your original file.
- `-o` - edit the "original" file rather than writing a new file.

If dos2unix isn't available, a number of other built-in tools may be able to do a similar job.

If you're running Linux, you can use GNU sed like this on just one file:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' files.txt
```

Or to process all text files in the current directory:

```
for file in *.txt; do sed -i 's/\r$//' "$file"; done
```

Or to run this recursively, if you're using bash version 4 or higher:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.txt; do sed -i 's/\r$//' "$file"; done
```

Another option for converting your line endings might be perl:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' files.txt
```

You could easily make it handle multiple files either in one directory or recursively in a similar way to the options above, if you want.

One more option might be to *leave the files as-is*, and do your conversion as you process the `files.txt` in bash. For example:

```
while read line; do
    find . -name "${line%$'\r'}" 
done < files.txt > outfile.txt
```

This uses the shell's parameter expansion combined with bash's format expansion to "strip" the offending CR character from the end of each variable as it is read by your while loop.

---

Also of note:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_utilities

Comment: You're very welcome! If this solves your problem, please feel free to close the question by clicking the green check mark on the left of the answer.